# Два вопроса о расширениях для Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

**Первый**

Не работает цикл кликов из `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: myscript.js
});` Клик только один раз хотя алерт виводиться несколько раз. Как исправить?

```
function Like() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document
            .querySelector(
                '#web-photorating-voting__0 > div.photo-vote-ctrl-section > div > button > span.photo-vote-ctrl-section-text'
            )
            .click();
    }, 2000);
}

for (var nom = 0; nom <= 5; nom++) {
    Like();
    alert(nom);
}
```

**Второй**

Как сделать функцию на кнопку старт-пауза-продолжить? Чтобы можно было скрипт приостановить при желании.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте сразу несколько разных вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на первый вопрос:

```
// начать повторы с интервалом 2 сек
var timerId = setInterval(function() {
document.querySelector("#web-photorating-voting__0 > div.photo-vote-ctrl-section > div > button > span.photo-vote-ctrl-section-text").click();
}, 2000);

// через 10 сек остановить повторы
setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
}, 10000);
```

Все просто.